# Cannot enter system after installing NVidia driver

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, nvidia, gpu-driver

I am trying to install a dual boot system (Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11) on my laptop. The GPU is 3050ti. After blacklisting Nouveau and installing the driver using the default options based on [the official website](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx) (I am sorry, but I cannot find the exact version of the driver since I cannot access the file system), the system will not boot. In fact, I only see a black screen, and there is no way to enter even the physical shell.

I am completely lost at what to do.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue in the past where after installing Nvidia drivers or updating the drivers automatically by `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`; it occurs to me that after like pressing enter to load ubuntu on Grub, the screen gets completely blank. So if that is the case(I think that is what happened to your system as the question you asked is not so clear so here is the solution that will help.

This kind of error mostly happen due to broken packages or not installation of drivers properly.

Make sure that you are connected to the internet before proceeding any further. If you primarily use wifi on your device, you could use ethernet or connect your PC to a mobile hotspot using USB tethering. Please ake sure that you have removed any other kind of unnecessary peripheral that is not primarily required.

**1. Access GRUB Menu:** During the boot process, try accessing the GRUB menu. After powering on your computer, hold down the Shift key or the Esc key (or sometimes the Tab key) until the GRUB menu appears.

**2. Boot into Recovery Mode:** In the GRUB menu, select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" or a similar option, and then choose the recovery mode for the latest kernel. From there, you can try to fix broken packages or configure your graphics drivers.

**3. Remove NVIDIA Drivers:** Boot into recovery mode, open a terminal, and remove the NVIDIA drivers. If you get logged in as root you could just skip on entering the `sudo` in the code.
How do you know you are root? There is this `#` that says you are in root ode and `@` says you are in user mode.
You can use the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

This will remove the NVIDIA drivers and regenerate the initramfs.

**4. Use the Nouveau Driver:** Instead of installing the proprietary NVIDIA driver, you can try using the open-source Nouveau driver. Boot into recovery mode, open a terminal, and run:

```
sudo apt purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Once you get into the system you can in later stages download any required compatible driver you want.

**4. Update GRUB Configuration:** Boot into recovery mode, open a terminal, and update the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

These should work and once you enter into the system you can install the latest NVIDIA drives from the `settings > about > software updates > additional drivers >`  Use the latest one and it should get you going. I also have attached a screenshot of this.

[image: The Scrrenshot of my system settings]